# Backbone Validation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, backbone.js

I used the Backbone validation plugin (available from: https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation). 
I also used Bootstrap 3. And I want to validate onChange or onBlur events.

I used it as such:

In Models.js, I have such rules:

```
   validation: {
       miliage: {
          required: true,
          pattern: 'number',
          msg: 'Укажите корректный пробег'
       },
       email : {
          required: true,
          pattern: 'email',
          msg: 'Укажите корректный email'
       },
    },
```

In Views.js after rendering html I bind the validation plugin:

```
Backbone.Validation.bind( this, {
   valid: function( view, attr, selector ) {
       console.log('valid');
       console.log( attr );
       control = view.$('[' + selector + '=' + attr + ']')
       group = control.parents(".form-group")
       group.removeClass("has-error");
       group.find(".help-block").remove();
   },
   invalid: function( view, attr, error, selector ) {
       console.log('invalid');
       console.log( attr );
       control = view.$('[' + selector + '=' + attr + ']');
       console.log( control );
       group = control.parents(".form-group");
       group.addClass("has-error");
       group.find(".help-block").remove();
       group.append("<span for="+attr+" class='help-block'>"+error+"</span>");
  }
```

});

I display error messages using the Bootsrap rules.

In this view, I have events like this:

```
 "change #email"     : "setEmail",
 "change #miliage"   : "setMiliage",
```

And appropriate functions (I set values to the model accordingly):

```
setMiliage : function( event ) {       
     console.log( $( event.currentTarget ).val() );
     this.model.set('miliage', $(event.currentTarget).val(),{validate : true});
},
setEmail : function( event ) {
     this.model.set('email', $(event.currentTarget).val(),{validate :true})
},
```

As you can see, I pass the params validate:true to method set - in order to validate each time when onChange event fires

**Problem:** Validation is performed on each aspect of the model (all of it's attributes) that is why the callback function **valid** and **invalid** fire on each attribute that is defined in the validation rules. I have two fields or more which require validation and when user change text in any of them  - in all fields performed validation.

**Example:** When the user opens the page for the first time - fields 'miliage' and 'email' are empty and when they typed a value into the first field (miliage) the other field indicates that an error has occurred - because it is still empty (user have not enter it yet) and i want to show message only for the first field. In other words, of course the second field is invalid so far, the user hasn't gotten there yet.

**Question:** Is there a way to perform validation on one current field the only one the user has changed, and display errors only related to it? I also want to put value into a model when it is invalid - I want it to show errors only. Also, I  want to perform control validation on submit form (before backbone save method)

I know there is the isValid(field) method which can validate only one field - but it does not trigger valid or invalid events

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way would be tracking which fields has been changed at least once and ignore validation errors on other fields when you're handling 'change' or 'blur' event.  Of course, this does not apply to handling 'submit', where no fields should be ignored

Comment: Thank you. i solved it by not set default value in model for this inputs. No attribute in model - no validation on change or blur but it is still works on before submit entire model validation (when model.validate() trigger)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem (validate only changed inputs) by not setting default value in model for this inputs - validation works only on attributes, that are already in model. When i need onChange onBlur validation i use model.set('email','test@email.com',{validate:true}), when entire model - model.validate() or model.save()