# How to validate if a Model parameter already exist in another model in the Collection?

Tags: backbone.js

How to validate if a Model parameter (Example name) already exist in another model in the Collection?

Comment: see [the quastion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326176/backbone-validation-issue)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) methods to find other models in the collection. So if you are looking for a specific name in the collection you could do:

```
var searchName = 'name from the model you are looking for';
var items = this.model.where({ name: name }); // model is a collection.
if (items.length) {
    // Validation logic.
}
```